# Nuxt JS: How to change build target

Tags: vite, nuxt3, esbuild

I am working on a nuxt3 application. I want to use a library for rendering state charts https://github.com/sverweij/state-machine-cat.

When I import this library in nuxt application and start dev server by command `npm run dev`, I get the error: `Top-level await is not available in the configured target environment ("chrome87", "edge88", "es2020", "firefox78", "safari14" + 2 overrides)`

[image: Nuxt dev server error]

I tried changing build target described in https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/14348 but still the error persists. We checked with author of the library also and he suggested also to target the recent browser. Ref: https://github.com/sverweij/state-machine-cat/issues/194

Could someone help on how to change build target in Nuxt 3